# Need help understanding bindings in Scheme code

Tags: variables, binding, scheme

For the code below, I am unable to comprehend how the bindings (x, y, z) occur. Please check out the code, I'll explain my problem in greater detail below:

```
(define (w x)
  (lambda (y z)
    (begin 
      (set! x (+ (* y x) z)) x)))
(define f1 (w 3))
(f1 4 2)
(f1 2 1)
```

The output is 14, 29. These are values for x.

This means initially, x=3, y=4, z=2. In the 2nd call, i.e. (f1 2 1), x=14, y=2,z=1.

My doubts:

How does the binding occur at first, why is x=3, y=4, and z=2? If it has got to do with lambda expression in the function, please elaborate on how it works..I have a feeling this is where my understanding breaks down..

Next, why is the initial answer of x=14 retained in the second call, i.e. (f1 2 1)?

Thank you for looking into this :)

Answer (score 4):

When `w` is run, it creates a *closure* out of the inner lambda.  Because `x` came from outside of that inner lambda, `x` is stored inside that closure (in this case, `f1`).

So, `f1` has a variable inside that represents `x`, and it starts out as 3.  When you run `f1`, it evaluates the math and then sets *its own* `x` to be 14.

The moral is, a `lambda` is more than just code; it's code combined with the variables it *closes over*, such as this `x`.

Comment: well, the simple answer is that it's created by `lambda`. Once the `lambda` is run, the function is converted by Scheme into an internal closure (code + environment) that you probably can't see.

Comment: this still puzzles me. How do you control how many variables are being created by your lambda expression that are internal?